# How to set up data for "ranger" in R. Error: Missing data in columns

Tags: r, missing-data, r-ranger

Code:

```
ranger(outcome~., data, num.trees=500, probability=TRUE)
```

Error: Missing data in columns

Is there a format that the data needs to be in? How to get past this error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To answer your question correctly, people will need to see what your data looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove NAs
Example:

```r
ranger(outcome~., data[complete.cases(data),], num.trees=500, probability=TRUE)
```

Other methods use packages like `mice` or `miceFast` to impute (fill NA).
Other simple solution to impute the data with random data (from each column).

```r
data_cs = data.frame(Map(function(x) Hmisc::impute(x,'random'), data))
ranger(outcome~., data_cs, num.trees=500, probability=TRUE)
```